# how to calculate proper proportions to make drinkable wine

Tags: wine

it's (fairly) easy to read a recipe that's already out there, or use a kit that someone else has already pre-packaged all the ingredients.  but i would like to take it to the next step and be able to calculate the correct proportions myself.

if i have a grape, how can i figure out its sugar content?  how do you know the correct proportions of sugar/liquid/yeast?  how do you know when to move to secondary (tertiary) fermentation?  if you alter those lengths, how will that alter the end product and which characteristics will be altered?

Comment: I suggest you pick up a book -- those are some broad questions you're asking :)

Comment: I've added a close vote to this question, because it's too far too broad, and there are way too many separate questions in this one question post. Please consider breaking this up into multiple questions that can be addressed individually.

Comment: I will close this - it's asking too many broad questions. @user1248888 - please try to focus on one question per post .